# Check if intent is empty or not

Tags: java, android

I have a rating bar in one activity and once a rating is chosen I want it to pass the value through an intent back to the main activity for display in an alert dialog. Here is the code and it works fine:

```
public void addListenerOnRatingBar() {

    ratingBar = (RatingBar) findViewById(R.id.ratingBar);
    txtRatingValue = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtRatingValue);

    //if rating value is changed,
    //display the current rating value in the result (textview) automatically
    ratingBar.setOnRatingBarChangeListener(new RatingBar.OnRatingBarChangeListener() {
        public void onRatingChanged(RatingBar ratingBar, float rating,
                                    boolean fromUser) {

            txtRatingValue.setText(String.valueOf(rating));
            String numStars = String.valueOf(rating);
            Intent a = new Intent(getBaseContext(), MainActivity.class);
            a.putExtra("numStars", numStars);
            startActivity(a);

        }
    });

}
```

On the main activity I am trying to set up an if statement so that the alert dialog only comes up if the string isn't empty but it's crashing the program everytime. Here is the code:

```
Bundle extra = getIntent().getExtras();
    String numStars = extra.getString("numStars");
    if (numStars.length() == 0) {
        final AlertDialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
        dialog.setMessage("Thank you for rating this app " + numStars + " Stars! ");
        dialog.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                }
        );
        dialog.show();


    }
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Make it `if (numStars != null && numStars.length() > 0)`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Switch:

```
String numStars = extra.getString("numStars");
```

To this:

```
String numStars = getIntent().getStringExtra("numStars");
```

Since you're passing a String to MainActivity & not a bundle, of course your `extra` bundle will always be null.

Comment: That will not work because the method is called on the bundle `extras`. `getStringExtra()` is to be called on an intent

Comment: Now it works but there is no difference between the two lines

Comment: He's passing a string, not a bundle to MainActivity.

Comment: Intent.getExtras() returns a Bundle object. The 2 lines you have here do exactly the same

Comment: getIntent().getStringExtra() returns a String. Look it up.

Comment: Ah yes! That fixed it, thank you. I was retrieving the intent wrong!

Comment: You're welcome. Please don't forget to accept and upvote the answer.

Comment: @Haldamir but how? This code changes nothing. I am curious how this solved the problem

Comment: *Since you're passing a String to MainActivity & not a bundle, of course your extra bundle will always be null.* - that is not true. The string you add to the intent with `putExtra()` is stored in the bundle

Answer (score 1):

```
String numStars = extra.getString("numStars");
if (numStars.length() == 0) {
```

This is not the correct way to check if the value exists or not.

If a value does not exist in a Bundle, attempting to get it returns `null`, therefore you must check it like this:

```
String numStars = extra.getString("numStars");
if (numStars == null) {
```

Keep in mind that if you have not added data to the intent with `putExtra()`, the bundle will be empty and `getIntent().getExtras()` will return null. So for that scenario it would be wise to also add a `if (extra == null)` check.

---

It is also possible to provide a default value that `getString` should return if the value wasn't found. In that case you can use `numStars.length() == 0)`:

```
String numStars = extra.getString("numStars", "");  // default value of ""
if (numStars.length() == 0) {
```